# Notify when profile form is submitted does not work (form with attached files)

Tags: profile, forms

I have created an application form in CiviCampaign through Petitions.

Everything has been set up fine, except that even after adding one or several emails in Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Profiles and click "Settings" on the profile created for this form in the Advanced Settings section "Notify when profile form is submitted" nothing ever happens when a form is submitted.

This is particularly important because we are requesting that two files are attached before submitting and we can't get access to them through civicrm backoffice. I was expecting they would be sent in the notification email.

We are using CiviCRM in Joomla, so this was the only solution I found to create an application form, without using CiviContribute, which does not apply to what we need. When we use CiviContribute the email notification works fine.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I actually begun, in petitions, by creating customised fields for the questions as "activity", but I could not find the data anywhere when I simulated a form submission, so I redid them as "individual" so they would show in the individual profile, especially if later we would need to do a search based on one or more answers for the questions. However, you mention that I can collect data with a Standalone profile. I did create a profile for this and then I used it in Petitions. How can I create a page where the data can be filled without using Petitions?

Comment: Well, I decided to go see the customised profile and its options. I found out the link for it as standalone form. You are absolutely right. No need for Petitions. I ended up with that solution after some google search and after all it is not necessary. I am now receiving the email notification and the attachments are being saved in our server and are available to be downloaded in contacts. Thank you and I am sorry for my lack of experience!

Comment: Alas, we receive the application email, but the applicant does not receive any confirmation email themselves (they do end up in a confirmation webpage though). I am already searching for a possible solution, but any help would be really great.

Comment: If you want a notification to go to the person who filled in the form, I would suggest reading up about what can be done with CiviRules. For example, on the Profile you could 'add applicant to a group' and then use Rules based on 'added to group' to trigger a notificiation (I think). Also it can really help if you set out what the outcomes are that you need. In this case, am i right in saying eg,

Comment: A person needs to fill in an application form and upload a file at the same time.. The data is to be stored on their contact record. We need them to receive a notification email, and we need and adminstrator to be informed that an application has been made.

Comment: Thank you very much. I installed both civirules and API extensions and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

A partial answer. If you want an 'application form' then a standalone Profile should suffice. There is no reason i know of why you would need to add complexity of CiviCampaign and Petitions.

Comment: Well, a standalone profile form can't save an activity, so all questions would have to be contact custom fields - not ideal.

Comment: I reread the question and saw no mention of Activity. I am not sure why i read this differently with the blurry eyes of 6am. But my first reading of it caused me to think that perhaps the user was not aware that a Standalone Profile could be used to collect data. And I wanted to make that point but perhaps should have done so via a Comment.

Comment: Maybe because I read 'application form' as 'we needed an Application Form and the way I saw that I could do so was by creating a Petition' - but Petition to me doesn't fit as a natural solution for 'we need people to apply for something' but maybe without webform this is a good solution ;-)

Comment: Yea petition is probably the best you can do with vanilla Civi.